# Remove repository from sources.list.d

Tags: repository, apt

I have a repo in my `sources.list.d/raspi.list` that I can't seem to remove.

I'm able to remove the repo from the list (`sudo vi`) and save it, but when I reboot the old file is restored.

How can I change `sources.list.d/raspi.list` permanently?

Furthermore, when I remove the key for this repo (`sudo apt key del <HEX>`) it is removed from `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`, but returns after a reboot.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but I once experienced similar problems and it turned out to be SD card corruption.